# Couldn't connect to vault server using e2vault api in java

Tags: java, devops

am trying to connect to our vault server hosted in a know IP using vault api "e2vault.jar" through my java application.

*note:

1. I can connect to the server remotly. so my device ip are connected to the server
2. When i use the runnable jar of my application in the vault server, i works successfully
   *

sample code:

```
VaultClient vaultClient = new VaultClient();
vaultClient.connect("Vault_Server_IP", 6002);
```

Comment: What's the error/exception it's throwing?

Comment: it doesn't throw any exception. "Connection Timeout"

Comment: any help?! does anyone has any idea?